# Avoiding multiple use of signed identities while not learning anything about them

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, data-privacy

There is an authority **A** with an associated public/private key pair (**A**.priv, **A**.pub).

**A** can issue new "identities" by signing data (numbers or bytestrings).
Each number associated with a signature by **A** is an identity. Here are two examples:

identity_1 = (sign(A.privkey, 1), 1)

identity_2 = (sign(A.privkey, 2), 2)

How can owners of these identities prove on a *public* system that they

1. have a valid identity without revealing their number
2. have not done this proof on the public system before?

Assuming the authority doesn't sign any data more than once, is it sufficient if identity owners just send the signature to the public system or does it tell anything about the data?

Comment: Assuming that the id numbers being signed are at least 128 bits and randomly chosen such that they cannot be guessed, and given that signature schemes normally sign a hash of the data, the owner of the identity can just publish the hash of their id number along with the signature. It will be obvious if that owner ever publishes the same id hash again. If this method is used, then it doesn't matter if the authority provides more than one signature for the same id.